# Difference between RTTI and reflection in Java

Tags: java, reflection, terminology, rtti, instanceof

My question is when how does the class info gets loaded during runtime?

When someone calls `instanceof` is that considered RTTI or reflection? Or it depends on the actual situation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The term "[RTTI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information)" is a C++-specific term referring to the functionality of the core language that allows the program to determine the dynamic types of various objects at runtime.  It usually refers to the `dynamic_cast` or `typeid` operators, along with the associated `std::type_info` object produced by `typeid`.

The term reflection, on the other hand, is a generic term used across programming languages to refer to the ability of a program to inspect and modify its objects, types, etc. at runtime.

The term I've heard applied to `instanceof` is *[type introspection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_introspection#Java_Object_Introspection)* and `instanceof` is sometimes referred to as *object introspection*, as the program is allowed to look at the running types to determine what course of action to take.  I think this is a weaker term than reflection, as it doesn't allow for elaborate introspection on the fields or methods of an object, but I don't think it would be technically incorrect to call the use of the `instanceof` operator reflection.

As to your other question - how does class information get loaded at runtime? - that's really up to the JVM implementation.  The `ClassLoader` type is ultimately responsible for loading classes into the system, but the JVM can interpret this however it wants to.  I once built a prototype JVM in JavaScript, and internally all reflection calls just queried the underlying JS data structures I had in place to represent classes, fields, and methods.  I would imagine that the HotSpot JVM does something totally different, but it's pretty much implementation-defined.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks! Somehow I learned about RTTI in my Java course, which was probably why I got confused :S